# Universal covering that induces zero on homologies

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $p:\tilde{X}\rightarrow X$ be the universal covering space such that $p_*$ is zero on all homologies of dimension greater than zero. Does this imply that $X$ is $K(\pi_1(X),1)$? Working with the second homology groups implies that Hurewicz homomorphism $\pi_2(X)\rightarrow H_2(X)$ is zero while $\pi_2(\tilde{X})\rightarrow H_2(\tilde{X})$ is an isomorphism. I cannot derive any contradictions from here. So maybe it is not true.

Comment: excuse me, would you please explain what is your notation $K(\pi_1(X),1)$ means?

Comment: It is the Eilenberg-Maclane space. The first homotopy group is $\pi_1(X)$ the higher ones are zero.

Comment: Oh~~is it Eilenberg–MacLane space
?

Comment: Ok~I got it, thanks

Comment: I think I found the counterexample. $\mathbb{RP}^{2n}$.

Comment: @user127776 I think it is a valid counter-example. You may want to put that in an answer to close this question then. :)

Answer (score 1):

A counter-example: $\mathbb{RP}^n$